# Reminding my professor to update a grade?

Tags: email, vocabulary, letter

I am writing an email to my professor as a reminder to update my grade on a particular assignment. I had an assignment that is graded based on a written essay and a presentation. I submitted the written part on time, but I delivered the presentation about a week late. I received a partial grade for the written part, but my professor has yet to update the grade to reflect my presentation.

The email doesn't have to be extremely formal, but I do want to remain very polite. The message is really a reminder, but I thought it would be more polite if I framed it as a question. So far I have:

---

Hello,

This is XXXX from your XXXX class on Tue/Thu mornings. I received a grade in for the written part of the XXXX assignment only, as I just completed the in-class presentation last Thursday. Could you please let me know when I should be expecting an updated grade reflecting my presentation as well?

---

Can you guys tell me if I am sounding rude or if there is a better way to phrase this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of questions what I would recommend is to begin as straight forward and precise as possible, and add the politeness after. If you're worried about not irritating someone, first thing to consider is clarity.

Here's how I would've written it:

This is XXXX from your Tue/Thu mornings XXXX class.

I'm wondering about the grading of the XXXX assignment presentation I did last Thursday. I did get the grading for the written part, but still wondering about the presentation. Could you please let me know when can I expect this?

Thank you!